# the equivalent of sscanf_s in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, scanf

`UnlockOffset` is *DWORD*. `thisKey` is a *char[5]*

```
if(EOF == sscanf_s(thisKey, "%d", &UnlockOffset))
```

How would the above code be done in c# ?

`DWORD` was converted to `UInt32` and `thiskey` remained `char` array but I still dont understand the `sscanf_s`.

PS: I did check MSDN but was not able to understand it very well which was why I posted it here.

Comment: I implemented `sscanf()` in C# [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sscanf_s` basically reads a string and extracts stuff that matches the format string.  It'll return `EOF` if it couldn't extract stuff to match all the format thingies.

You could do something like

```
string str = new string(thisKey);
if (!UInt32.TryParse(str, out UnlockOffset))
```

which would accomplish something similar, but it might be more or less strict.  `UInt32.TryParse` returns true if it could convert the string and false if it couldn't, so checking for EOF would be equivalent to seeing whether TryParse is false.

Comment: Thanks I was also wondering where that EOF was coming from ;)

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you would use [`UInt32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.parse.aspx) (or `TryParse`) to pull the information out of a `string`.  It is rare that `char[]` is used to store string values in C#, as `string` is more appropriate.

Comment: Well I left it as a char initially because I was trying to convert the code, since I didnt know well how to convert the sscanf_s until now I didnt bother to change it to string.

Answer (score 0):

If thisKey is "123 456 739" then `sscanf_s(thisKey, "%d", &UnlockOffset))` would get 123 into `UnlockOffset`
Here's an approximate equivalent

```
string str = new string(thisKey);
string[] strAr = str.Split(' ');
UnlockOffset = Convert.ToUInt32(strAr!=null ? strAr[0] : str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone has already mentioned `uint.Parse` (and `uint.TryParse`), you can convert your char array to an integer like this:

```
uint UnlockOffset = 0;
foreach (char digit in thisKey)
{
    UnlockOffset *= 10;
    UnlockOffset += (uint)(digit - '0');
}
```

Comment: Assuming the array doesn't have any garbage in it, like leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: @cHao in some cases it has a `-` within it.

Comment: @Prix: There's that too.  Which would cause issues when you're going char by char.  (But for reference, `UInt32` is *unsigned* -- meaning if you're looking to parse a negative number, you probably won't get the value you're expecting anyway...)